# force update groups - su self wont work - non root - only have ssh login

Tags: linux, group, su

System administrator added me to a group but I don't see the effects yet.
For example,

```
> groups # does not return the desired group
```

I (and all other users) only have the ssh login option to connect to the machine (`su <self>` is not option since I have locked password). It is a shared cluster so re-booting is not an option.

Do I have any other options apart from logging out and logging in again?

Comment: Either logout/login (group membership is set at login) or, to get one process in the new group, `newgrp` will do it. Read `man newgrp`.

Comment: @roaima I have used exit/logout / cmd + c commands to logout, countless times. I also pkill -u <myself> but it is also not worked. Am I missing something very basic to logout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you can only get to the remote system(s) with `ssh`. So if you logon and you haven't got the new group then it's not been added to your account.

Comment: you are indeed correct, it turns out that I added for another node's group.